# Free virtualization system with clone vm feature

Tags: virtualization, xen, kvm-virtualization

I need virtualization system, based on kvm or Xen with Web interface, or windows gui, which support cloning vms. One more point is that I can not install it from iso (server is located in hetzner). Proxmox is almost what I need, but it does not support cloning vms. Any recommendations?

Comment: Dekstop virtualization or server virtualization?

Comment: Server, with windows and Linux guest support.

Comment: What is so difficult about cloning? `dd` will do the job. After that you will have to change names, IPs and in the case of windows SIDs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the new RHEV 3 - the current beta is free to try. For a standalone machine there's also the [virt-clone](http://linux.die.net/man/1/virt-clone) tool which is a part of libvirt. There is no web manager as such, but if you can ssh to the host you can either use the CLI or `ssh -X` and use virt-manager

Comment: RHEV seems to be right what I need. Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

I use and am quite happy with Citrix Xen Center, it comes with a very nice gui for windows.

It has a free version and a paying version that has more features (live migration).